# Dividing range of territory into squares with different colors from points with accident information using QGIS

Tags: qgis, network-analysis

[image]

I have points with accident information and I need to divide the range of my territory into squares with different colors.

And the coloring of the square must depend on how many points (accidents) lie within its boundaries.

How can I achieve this using QGIS?

The picture above is an example of what I want to make

Comment: I think you're over thinking this. It sounds like you just want to convert points to raster, where your raster value will be the number of points per cell. Just a simple format conversion, which doesn't involve networks or statistics.

Comment: Point density?  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/point-density.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a grid. In QGIS, this is done in the `Vector - Research Tools - Create a Grid`. The grid should cover the extent of your point data.

For example, if you have the locations of all Pokemon in your city, you could make a rectangular grid with side length 1 km. From the Pokemon locations, you can then use the grid to show the density of Pokemon per square km. Below you can see the Pokemon and the grid. There are two clusters in the north, and low density in the south.

[image]

To calculate the density, use the `Vector - Analysis - Count Points in Polygon` tool. This will create a grid of polygons with a feature NUMPOINTS that gives the number of Pokemon in each square. Note the red in the north and the low density in the south. It's a 1 square km grid, so the NUMPOINTS attribute represents the density of Pokemon per square km.

[image]